# Gltf model texture and scene bin not found

Tags: aframe, gltf

I searched a lot of solutions online but none helped. I tried putting the gltf model on this website (https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) and it is working fine but when I tried using it on glitch the texture and scene.bin file failed to load. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/feline-lifter?path=index.html:21:13

Error im getting:
[image: Error im getting]

I kept getting this error and I don't know how to fix it! also this is my html code:
[image: html code]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide the code which you have tried so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267892/gltf-file-not-showing-in-aframe) anwser your question ?

Comment: @Tox  https://glitch.com/edit/#!/feline-lifter?path=index.html:21:13 u can try it here bro my code is all there at index

Answer (score 1):

The errors suggest that something is trying to find resources at

```
https://cdn.glitch.com/textures/*something*.jpg
```

That *something* would be the GLFT Loader, which is fed with sinister lies in the  **.gltf** file:

```
"buffers": [
{
  "byteLength": 12440812,
  "uri": "scene.bin"
}
],
"images": [
{
  "uri": "textures/alpha_baseColor.png"
},
{
  "uri": "textures/alpha_metallicRoughness.png"
},
(...)
```

if you look up the paths to the assets, they are neither in the **textures** folder nor in ..any folder. They are wherever glitch decides to throw them. So the paths in the **.gltf** file are not valid when it's being loaded at a glitch hosted website.

Either:

1. Convert the model to **.glb**, which consists all resources
2. Throw the model on github where paths are relative, making the paths valid.
3. Change the paths using the glitch assets links.

Comment: Thank you seems like I made it using glb. Tho its sad that I cant use gltf! Merry christmas