# A-Frame Issues in Glitch

Tags: aframe

I can't seem to import JPG or GLTF models into a-frame despite me tagging it correctly using glitch.

Comment: Please add a code sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267892/gltf-file-not-showing-in-aframe) answer